# Solutions/Algorithms to cut an object from image- Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

Folks,

First I'd like you guys to have a look at this app "Image cut": https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.zx1234567890.imagecut.

This app very neatly cuts an object of importance from a user defined area
inside an image. You can simple sketch an area around the object you want to
cut out by moving around your finger on the screen. Then the app takes out
the object with a great preciseness.

I am no Image Processing kid, but I can try playing with algorithms.My question is 
to all you Image-Processing/Algorithm guys that how should I go about implementing
this. I mean if you can describe how complex problem is this to solve and how should I
approach this problem. I did google around but wasn't able to get a concrete picture
of the possible solution. Since the above mentioned app has achieved this, it seems the problem
should be solvable. I'll highly appreciate any help here.

Thank you!

Comment: All I could figure out was that this app uses openCV and that SIOX, a strong Object Detection Library, is a good candidate for solving this problem. Is any Image-Processing/Computer Vision/Graphics geek out there to help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is called "semi-supervised image segmentation" (I am sure other names exist). Specifically you are trying to perform a "binary segmentation", labeling the pixels with two classes (foreground and background).

OpenCV contains an algorithm called GrabCut, that would work quite well with the example image in the app. The object that is extracted is very different from the background

GrabCut is very resource hungry, so you need to be smart about using it on a phone (e.g. resize the input image). Maybe you should play around with it on a desktop computer first.

Comment: Hey,Thank you bjoernz! I hope the android-OpenCV jar does support the GrabCut wrapper. I'll check it out soon and try- will talk more about this once I test using it.

Answer (score 0):

apply magic wand tool somewhere near selected zone and remove everything outside selected zone. Possible problems to adjust sensitivity.

ON example image result is fine with high sensitivity, becouse there are clear edges.

Comment: I am looking at coding/Algorithmic solutions to this problem. Guys, is it possible with OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this process is called Segmentation. I know this is old but for any new comers, you can checkout TensorFlow. They provide object segmentation models for both Android and iOS.

[TensorFlow Segmentation for Mobile & IOT](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/segmentation/overview)